# Stop generating QuickReport in a bandBeforePrint Event in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi-5, quickreports

may be someone can help.

I work with Delphi 5, QuickReport Version 3.0.

I need to cancel report generation upon getting some value in Band1BeforePrint.
I can do it in the QuickRep1BeforePrint by setting PrintReport to False.

But the problem is that QuickRep1BeforePrint occurs before Band1BeforePrint and I don't have access to PrintReport any more.

I tried work around by setting global variable in Band1BeforePrint, but it's not read again by report.

Any suggestions how can I stop generation the report?
Is there any way I can call again QuickRep1BeforePrint from Band1BeforePrint?

Thanks in advance!